# Can I use PWM to lower the supply to an EM brake

Tags: power, pwm, switching, electromagnetic

I am working on a board that is supplied from 48v battery. the design contains multiple dc/dc converters (5v,3.3v). one the functions of this design is to control an Electromagnetic brake (24v 1A up to 2A).

I usually use a low side or high side switch for this function (which is basically a mosfet with all the protection circuitry built into one package).

I would like to save cost by not using a regulator to generate the 24v required for the brake.

**My Question** is can I use PWM (50% duty @ 1khz or 10khz) feed into the low side switch to trick the brake into seeing only 24v ?

**My worries are:**

1. I doubt that the internal coil insulation cannot handle the 48v , but the dv/dt of switching can be harmful ?!
2. The braking power is reduced or lost , since the coil is rated at DC.

regards

Comment: If you smooth out the PWM with a low pass filter, it'll be lower voltage DC. Might be as simple as a reservoir capacitor. Of course, PWM + LPF has another name ... buck convertor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's really just a coil and doesn't contain electronics, unfiltered PWM of a suitable frequency will work fine. The inductance of the coil will provide the required filtering. Don't forget the free-wheeling diode, which must be a high-frequency low-voltage-drop type (i.e. a Schottky). The free-wheeling diode will conduct during the PWM off-time and must therefore be able to handle the full coil current continuously.